# SSIS facing Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream-Exception

Tags: ssis, oledb, sendmail

I want to check some data from CRM or a database, prepare them via script-task and send the data via mail task. I configured an SMTP connection (no win auth, using SSL), which I'm using in all my dtsx.

The control flow:

[image]

The data flow:

[image]

So what I'm doing right now is collecting data via Kingswaysoft adapter or via OLE DB connection and prepare them in the script task. The data will be written into three output variables that are used in the mail send task.

While every dtsx using the CRM-adapter is working perfectly and sending the expected mails, the dtsx which are using OLE DB facing the Error: **System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream**

I tried to disable the data flow task and send a pre-filled mail (without using variables) and I faced the same error.

Now I don't understand why the *CRM-Tasks* working fine and emails sent while the others don't send anything. Data is received from the OLE DB source and is prepared well, but failed in the sending task.4

Any ideas here?

Comment: Is the error in the task that extracts data or the task that sends the email?

Answer (score 1):

I get this a lot when the remote server has turned on requiring tls. Try adding this at the top of your script task...

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```